# converting rows into multiple columns

Tags: excel, function, indexing

need help with index function. i have a bunch of data on row A and need to split them to two rows instead but retaining their alphabetical order. 
as the image shows.

[example of what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KZ1G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put this following standard formula in C1,

```
=INDEX($A:$A, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/7)*14+MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, 7)+SIGN(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*7+1)&""
```

Copy it to E1 then fill both down until you run out of entries.

[image: Split Columns of data with formula]