# How to increment row value in excel INDEX formula using fill handle?

Tags: excel, indexing

I have an excel sheet with two columns A and B. Sample data is as follows:

```
ColA           ColB 
Name           Elmo 
Address1       125 Sesame Street 
Address2       Disney land, Fl 85381 
Name           Elsa 
Address1       35 Frozen island 
Address2       Disney land, Fl 85381
Address3       USA
```

And so on for a number of records. I would like to transpose this information using the index formula to read:

```
Name       Address1          Address2              Address3
Elmo       125 Sesame Street Disneyland, Fl 85381
Elsa       35 Frozen island  Disneyland, Fl 85381  USA
```

Using excel's `copy` and `paste-special`, `transpose` would be too time consuming as there are a number of records. I've listed the headers and used `D2=INDEX($B$1:$B$927,1)` for the values. I would like to use the fill handle to drag it across horizontally and  have the row number increment from 1 to 2 to 3, etc.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: See [converting rows into multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379059/converting-rows-into-multiple-columns/33405599#33405599)

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped this is very informative. I will learn more about it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your result table has Name, Address1, Address2 as headers, you can play around with the row number in each of them.

Cells under Name can have this formula: `=INDEX($B$2:$B$17,ROW()*3-5)`

Cells under Add1 can have this formula: `=INDEX($B$2:$B$17,ROW()*3-4)`

Cells under Add2 can have this formula: `=INDEX($B$2:$B$17,ROW()*3-3)`

(Pasted as values in column H,I,J in the picture for illustrative purposes only.)

[Sample Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qxwp.png)

Comment: Sorry, but I simply see no available solution provided here. Images are discouraged in a question's sample text and code ([Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)). Why would it be OK to answer with? This is worse than a link-only answer.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. Am new to SO. And didn't know about it. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Nice job and congrats of using the non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was very useful. How can I adjust it for rows where the data has more rows for some records? Eg. Elsa has three lines for address but the remainder of the records have 2.

Comment: This can be done using an INDEX-MATCH-ARRAY formula. Will provide that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,COLUMNS($B:B)-1+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*3,0)
```

then copy both across and down:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was very useful. I actually find this easier to use. How can I adjust it for rows where the data has more rows for some records? Eg. Elsa has three lines for address but the remainder of the records have 2.

Comment: @RTMohess  That might require a macro.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different answer because: requirements of the problem stated are different for the previous answer.

As a first step, you will need to add a "Name Counter" - this identifies how many unique people exist in your data. I have added that as Column A to the left of the data. The 1st value is 1 in A2. In A3, the formula is `=IF(B3="Name",A2+1,A2)`. This you can drag down all the way to the end of your data. (See screenshot)

In your result table, you will have to similarly add a Name Counter column which goes on from 1 to the no of unique Name entries. This is column E in my sample sheet (see screenshot)

The formula to enter for top-left most cell in your result table (in my example, this is cell F2) is
`{=INDEX($C$2:$C$25,MATCH($E2&F$1,$A$2:$A$25&$B$2:$B$25,0))}`.

Since this is an array formula, please type in only `=INDEX($C$2:$C$25,MATCH($E2&F$1,$A$2:$A$25&$B$2:$B$25,0))`
in your cell corresponding to F2 of mine, and then hit `Ctrl`+`Shit`+`Enter` to enter the formula. Excel will automatically put the curly brackets around it, and identify it as an array calculation.

You can copy paste this formula across to the remaining cells. (Since it is an array formula pasting the formula over itself will not work, so paste it only in the empty cells.)

[image: Sample Screenshot] (A,B,C - Data; E,F,G,H - Formulae; J,K,L,M - As Values)

Comment: this is brilliant and worked perfectly! It produced error values in the cells that did not have any information but that could was easily rid of. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not have reputation to be able to upvote your answer. :(

Comment: @RTMohess - this is what I found - you can check a green tick under the answer that indicates that it was the answer you were looking for. I didn't know that, and did that for one of the questions I asked.